# Why don't two files get made if I run the program twice?

Tags: java, file

I have a program that makes a file. I assume that if I run that program twice, I will get two of the same files? Or will one file just override the other? I made some code that says if the file already exists(If I already ran the program once) than to display a window saying that. But, for some reason, the code is always successful in making the new file?

```
package Files;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File; //The file class gives info about files, ex: length, existence, etc. (filename.exists();)
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Myfirstfileclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File myfile = new File("C:\\creationfiles\\jfklda.txt"); //Always use two backslashes, because one backslash escapes a swing, it interprets two as one though.

        if (! myfile.exists()) {
            newwindowsinceexists object = new newwindowsinceexists();




            final Formatter myformatter;

            try{ //Saying try this, if it gets an error then go over to catch.
                myformatter = new Formatter("Imadethisfileforyou.txt");
                System.out.println("It should have worked!");

                // This is the same as just making it all in one line, and writing:
                //final Formatter myformatter = new Formatter("Imadethisfileforyou.txt");
            }

            catch(Exception e){ //Execption is a fancy word for error
                Error error = new Error(); //Opens window saying you got an error
            }



        }

        if (myfile.exists()){
            alreadyexists existenceobj = new alreadyexists();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class alreadyexists extends JFrame{
    public alreadyexists(){
        super ("Did you run this program more than once?");

        JLabel didyou = new JLabel("Did you run this program more than once?");

        add(didyou);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(getMaximumSize());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

---

```
class newwindowsinceexists extends JFrame {

    public newwindowsinceexists() {

        super("I will create a new file for you!");

        JLabel text = new JLabel("I will create you a new file");
        text.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 30));

        add(text);

        setSize(getMaximumSize());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

---

```
class Error extends JFrame{

    public Error(){

        super("Sorry, there's an error!");

        JLabel labelerror = new JLabel("There is an error, I am sorry");
        labelerror.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 30));
        add(labelerror);

        setSize(250, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Does it override the file that has been created, and how can I stop that and make class alreadyexists run if it already has been created? Thank you for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer.

Comment: It looks like you’re creating a file named `Imadethisfileforyou.txt`, but checking to see if `C:\creationfiles\jfklda.txt` exists. Do you mean for those to be the same?

Comment: I don't see *any* line of code that actually creates/writes a file.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes icktoofay, I want them to be seperate, but when trying out myformatter.exists I get an error because  The method exists() is undefined for the type Formatter

Comment: @Andreas instantiation of Formatter creates new file, that is not the problem though, as I can see the file being made. :)

Comment: So totally not following what issue you have. Yes, javadoc for [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#method_summary) shows no method called `exists()`. Running the program twice, will still not see first file, so will execute the `new Formatter()` again, and it replaces the second file. Quoting [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.String%29): "If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size".

Comment: Instantiating a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) instance, does not create a file in the file-system. You need to write something for a file to be created. Similarly, instantiating a [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.String%29) does not create a file until something is written and it is `close`d.

Comment: There are other methods for creating files, have you looked into those?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, but is there anyway to not replace it, and instead create a new one of the same name...?

Comment: @Rich The file system won't allow that. You can't have two files with the same name in the same folder.

Comment: Alright then, so there is no way to achieve this without replacing one file? Thanks so much :)